# Windows store not downloading app

Tags: windows-10, download, windows-store

Ok so this is my first time using windows store to download something(Minecraft Windows 10 Edition). At first when i downloaded it, it was stuck and then I came to know that setting your connection as metered will block all the downloads from the store..

Then I set my connection as non-metered again and disconnected and reconnected. I tried the download again. But it is not showing the percentage of program downloaded- http://prntscr.com/dadx18                                            it just shows the "downloading.." thing

And then when I open the task manager it shows that the windows store is using 0mbps - http://prntscr.com/dadxje

That means that the download is stuck. I have already tried wsreset command multiple times but its still not working. Also I had disabled auto-updates and automatic downloads in windows settings and windows store to save up on connection.

Can anyone please help? I have been trying to download this game for more than 24 hours now but still...everytime..something goes wrong...

PS: I use windows 10 if someone didn't already understand..

Comment: Just to be sure, you are certain that your internet is working properly for other applications? Are you capable of downloading other things from the Windows Store or not?

Comment: yes..i can download from google play over the same connection..

Comment: Can you download other things from the Windows Store?

Comment: minecraft is the first thing that i have attempted...I dont know about other things so...

Comment: Just try downloading some small programme. This will help establish whether it's an issue with this particular download, or whether the whole windows store isn't working for you.

Comment: i presume that the whole store isn't working as I wsreset it and now I can't even click on an app to show the download button from the main page...I think I need to reinstall the store itself..